# How to decide when to round when converting decimal/int to float

Tags: c, floating-point

I have an integer -2147483647, which is 0x8000001 in hex.
When I use an online float converter, it says that it will instead convert -2147483648, due to rounding.

Now I have to implement this int-to-float function in c with single-precision.

I have all the other features already implemented but I was not aware of the rounding. 
When do I decide when to round?

**EDIT:
Here are the features I have so far. (in the order of how the function works)
1) First I check if the int is negative, in which I negate it and assign it to an unsigned int. I also set the sign bit to be 1.

2) To get the exponent, I search for the first '1' bit from the left of the unsigned int, and get its position.

3) I add 127 to the position and shift it 23 bits to the left to place to match the IEEE 754 standards.

4)  With the position Counter I had on 2), I align the unsigned int to the right so that the 31st bit is the second right-most '1'bit. (because you omit the first '1'bit as it is assumed in every IEEE float)

5) I right shift that int 9 bits to the right so that it fits the mantissa slot of the standard.

6) I add the sign bit, the exponent, and the mantissa to get the final bit representation of the original int.

Comment: @Barmar I think your math is off.  This quantity takes 32 bits. Won't fit in a float, but fine for a double.

Comment: 0x8000001 = 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000001. If you set that as a signed int it is very well -2147483647 by two's complement.

Comment: If you have implemented the other features, you should have already hit the problem of what to do when there are more than 23 significant bits in the significand. Rounding is the answer to that problem.

Answer (score 1):

The three closest values for -2147483647 in single precision, as shown in hex and the integer number are:

```
hex ceffffff = -2147483520
hex cf000000 = -2147483648
hex cf000001 = -2147483904
```

so hex cf000000 = -2147483648 is used since it's the closest.